# restrict T to a int value?

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

How can i solve this error msg?

```
static public class Blah
{
    public static T val<T>(this bool b, T v) { return b == true? v:0; }
}
```

error

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'T' and 'int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this in C#. You can do

`where T: struct`, and force T to be a value type, but that still isn't enough.

Or you can do

`default(T)`, which is 0 when T is an int.

Comment: Aren't you saying there's no way to do it, and then go on to list 2 ways to do it? :)

Comment: There is no way to say "T must be of a numeric type" in C#. My two approaches (which I'd use both together actually) are the best cludge you're gonna get :)

Although really, I'd probably adopt an entirely different approach to this problem.

Comment: @Jeff, he's saying there is no way to restict T to int, which is true. The first sample is showing how it can at least be limited to a value type. The second is showing how a default return value should be constructed, which will work for int, double, DateTime, object, Foo, etc.

Answer (score 14):

If you want T to be an int, accept an int and not a T. Otherwise, consider returning default(T) if b == false.

`return b ? v : default(T);`

If T is an int, it will return 0. If it is a reference type, it will be null. And on and on..

Answer (score 5):

Why are you trying to use generics if you only want an int?

```
// No need to compare b to true...
public static int val(this bool b, int v) { return b ? v : 0; }
```

Otherwise, use `default(T)` as others have mentioned.

```
public static T val<T>(this bool b, T v) { return b ? v : default(T); }
```

`default(T)` will default to 0 for `int`s and other numeric values, `false` for `bool`s, `null` for objects...

Comment: I suspect he wants to support int, long, double, etc so returning default(T) is probably the best option.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to return the "default" value for T:

```
public static T val<T>(this bool b, T v) { return b == true? v : default(T); }
```

[Default Values Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)
[default Keyword in Generic Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `v : 0` with `v : default(T)` , if you have a good reason for generics. If you need to restrict it to int, then you're not writing a generic class.

Comment: My guess is he doesn't really want int, but all numeric types (long, short, double, etc).

Comment: I wish we had that option, sometimes. (Or constraints to types that support certain mathematical operators).

Answer (score 2):

If there's only valid type for T then it shouldn't be generic:

```
public static int val(this bool b, int v)
{
    return b ? v : 0;
}
```

If you want this to work for any value type you could do this:

```
public static int val<T>(this bool b, T v) where T : struct
{
    return b ? v : default(T);
}
```

Comment: There's no particular reason that this code needs the `where T : struct`.

Answer (score 2):

Srsly!

To "restrict T to int" you take advantage of a special compiler feature known as `strong-typing`:

```
static public class Blah
{
    public static int val(this bool b, int v) { return b == true? v:0; }
}
```

Tada! :)

Seriously, why are you using generics?